# error: unexpected token in '.section' directive .section .text

Tags: xcode, assembly, arm

when I compile assembly 'xx.s' in xcode and there are some errors
"error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
.section .text
"
in xx.s the code is below:

```
.section .text

.global PreMDCT

PreMDCT:

stmdb     sp!, {r4 - r11, lr}

add         r9, r0, r1, lsl #2

sub         r3, r9, #32

movs        r1, r1, asr #2

beq         PreMDCT_END

.end
```

thanks

Comment: You might want to learn how to [format you code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 10):

While that is valid gcc / as code, it might not be valid xcode syntax.

The [xcode devoloper manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/Assembler/040-Assembler_Directives/asm_directives.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000823-TPXREF101) suggests that .text is a directive of its own and it's the first implicit directive. Thus it may works simply with

```
.text
.global asdf
asdf:
        nop
        ret
.end
```

or even without the first directive.

Comment: you are right,when I remove the .section.test directive,it can compile successfully,but it's not friendly to cross-compiler.is there any way to solve this problem.thanks :)

Comment: I suspect `.section SOME_OTHER_NAME  \n .text` will do.