# Declaring array of large size of vector<int> using gcc causes error. Changing to Clang works

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, arm, g++

In CLion, I have a declaration at the global scope:

`std::vector<int> adj[2e5];`

When I run the code on CLion, it gives me an error

```
error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
        .section .data.rel.ro.local
                                   ^
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

When I reduce the size of the array from `2e5` to something smaller, the error goes away.

I have added the following to CMake to increase stack size:

`set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-stack_size,0x20000000")`

However, the problem still appears. I recently switched from Intel MacBook Air to MacBook Pro M2 chip. In my previous laptop, this was never a problem and I never had to increase the stack size or anything. How can I get rid of this problem?

Full Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> adj[200000];

int main() {
   return 0;
}
```

**UPD:** I use gcc compiler which i downloaded via homebrew. if i switch to clang, the error goes away. the only problem: i don't want to use clang.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just declare a vector of vector?

Comment: @john Arrays are faster. Also, even if i do, runtime error is possible since I am working with large arrays. Also, I want to fix the underlying problem for future purposes. As I mentioned, this was never a problem with Intel MacBook and as I switch, I don't want this problem to be a headache. So, better resolve it now

Comment: *'Arrays are faster'*, not sure that is true. What is faster depends upon so many different factors that any blanket statement is guaranteed to be false. After all you have just changed computers, are you sure that what was true on your old computer is true on the new one, or any computer you might use in the future? Since fundamentally arrays and vectors have the same structure I would expect similar speed. Though of course in unoptimized code there will be a difference.

Comment: The error message suggests that you are attempting to use CLion(**XCode**) linker for the object files, which are produces by **gcc**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149545/error-unexpected-token-in-section-directive-section-text. Inspect the exact **command line** which is produced by CLion for compile your source file. Check, that this command line doesn't involve gcc compiler.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I use the gcc compiler for Clion which I downloaded via Homebrew (I don't want to use clang). So, the gcc compiler is to be involved.

Comment: And probably this is function local variable so this means you are overflowing the stack. Please provide [mcve] not just one line which is pointed by compiler. Context is important.

Comment: @Tsyvarev using clang makes the error go away... but, i still want to use gcc. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @MarekR see the update. using clang makes the error go away and the code works just fine. Any idea how I can make it work for gcc also? Thanks?

Comment: @MarekR The one line is enough to cause the error. The only thing i have in my file is includes and the main function. That's it

Comment: Note that `2e5` is a floating point literal. When I do `static_cast<std::size_t>(2e5)`, GCC compiles your code. I don't think this is a good idea, though.

Comment: @Friedrich I put `2e5` for information. I have tried `constexpr` and others to use the number. All of them result in error.

Comment: @Friedrich I have added the full code now

Comment: Thank you. Might be a GCC problem on ARM architecture. CMake and CLion seem unrelated. You might get better answers if you edit your tags accordingly.

Comment: You have 200000 vectors, and you hesitate to use another one?

Comment: @n.m. Using vector<vector<int>> runs but gives runtime error...

Comment: So there is a bug you need to fix. It's not like `vector<vector<int>>` inherently  causes runtime errors.